# Typekit not working in IE8

Tags: css, drupal, internet-explorer-8, font-face, typekit

I'm working on a site in Drupal, I have a font (Dax) that I am loading with Typekit, it is not displaying in IE8.

I did some research on Google but it appears that Typekit should work in IE8.  I had been using the Typekit editor to add the font to CSS selectors.  I tried adding the font name directly to the stack in my CSS file and using the special font names with weight included that are talked about on this page: http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/6855-using-multiple-weights-and-styles

It still does not work.  I'm not sure if this is a Drupal related problem as I normally do not work in Drupal.  It is also my first time working with Typekit.

Here is the link: http://inclusionbc.hhdev.hothousemarketing.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news, it doesn't work in (my) IE 9 as well. It should not have anything to do with Drupal. I've had problems with minified css/javascript and Typekit, but I can see you havn't compressed anything.

I see you are calling typekit as the last script in head. Try move it to the top. And use the advanced embed code instead. I would prefer to use a regular font-face declaration, but Typekit does not support this.

Comment: Moving the script to the top of head fixed it in IE :)  Thanks for the heads up on IE 9 as well, I sometimes neglect testing it because it usually behaves the same as current versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari.

Answer (score 0):

As descibed here http://outwardfocusdesign.com/ie-error-invalid-argument-when-using-typekit/ a unclosed tag was the fault. ( Use http://validator.w3.org/check on your code and look for "unclosed"-errors; Other errors do not affect typekit's JS )

Closing the tag correctly did the trick for me in IE8